# Как передать доступ к модели данных в js полученной из spring mvc+jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Spring MVC из Controller'а передается в jsp,  модель

Например,

```
class Data{
   List<Fields> fields;   - поля
   List<Calc> calculation; - вычисления
   class Calc{
      BigDecimal minAmount = 10;
      BigDecimal maxAmount = 20;
      BigDecimal total = 10;
   }
}
```

Пример поверхностный, только для описания

соответственно в jsp отображаются поля

```
<c:forEach items="${data.fields}" var="f">
```

подключаем js

```
resources type="js" path="/js/calc.js
```

В calc.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
тут задаю начальные значения
вешаю какие-нибудь обработчики событий, например,
$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
}}
```

Вопрос как в данном примере в calc.js получить доступ к data (переданной в представление jsp из контроллера) ?
Запомнить их например тут

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 /* var calc = data.calculation */
```

и использовать в вычислениях.
Встраивать js в jsp не хочу, нужно разделение

Думаю есть простой способ jquery или scope документа. Как вытащить эту информацию? Надеюсь понятно описал